# losing scope of ng-model when using ng-include (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

I am creating android app using ionic and angularjs. In app i used ng-include for include html content in my page.

**checkbox.html:**

```
<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="opt in $parent.checkboxOptions">
            <h4>
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.checkboxAnswer" value="{{opt.option_value}}">{{opt.option_value}}</label>
            </h4>
        </li>

</ul>
```

**surveyCtrl.js**

```
$scope.checkboxOptions = params.QuestAnswers;
$scope.next = function(){
    console.log($scope.checkboxAnswer);
}
```

its showing `undefined` and another thing when i am click on one checkbox its selecting all checkbox's also.

[image: checked all checkbox's by click on one]

**surveyCtrls.js**

```
 .directive('question', function ($compile) {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.question, function(QuesHtml) {
        ele.html(QuesHtml);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
       });
    }
  };
  })

 .directive('description', function ($compile) {
     return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.description, function(DescHtml) {
          ele.html(DescHtml);
          $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
          });
      }
    };
  })

 .directive('answers', function ($compile) {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
     replace: true,
      link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
       scope.$watch(attrs.answers, function(AnswerHtml) {
        ele.html(AnswerHtml);
       $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
     });
   }
  };
 })
.controller('surveyLoad', function($scope){


var QuestType  =  SurveyData[QuestionIndex].question_type;

var DrawHTML = {
                  'QuestionText': 'Some Text', 
                  'QuestionDesc': 'Some Desc',
                  'QuestAnswers': [{
                                      option_value: 'Red',
                                   }, {
                                      option_value: 'Blue',
                                   }];,
                  'scope'       : $scope
               };

  checkbox(DrawHTML);

}

})


 .controller('nextQuest', function($scope){

    $scope.QuestNext = function(){
       console.log($scope);
    }

 });


function checkbox(params){

   var $scope = params.scope;
   $scope.QuesHtml = "<p>"+params.QuestionText+"</p>";
   $scope.DescHtml = "<p>"+params.QuestionDesc+"</p>";

   $scope.checkboxOptions = params.QuestAnswers;
   $scope.AnswerHtml = "<div ng-include src=\"'surveyTemplate/checkbox.html'\"></div>";
}
```

**survey.html**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col question_div">
                <div class="qus_head">
                    <p>Question:  1/10</p>
                </div>
                    <h4 class="para"><span question="QuesHtml"></span> </h4>
                <div class="qus_footer">
                    <p>Maxime quis.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div answers="AnswerHtml">

        </div>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col button_div">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=""><img src="../img/next.png" style="width:70px;float:right" alt="next" ng-controller="nextQuest" ng-click="QuestNext()"></a></li>
                    <!-- <center><li><button style="align:center">Stop</button></li></center> -->
                    <li><a href=""><img src="../img/pre.png" style="width:70px;float:left" alt="previous" ></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

is there any way to get the value of checked checkboxes and prevent to check all other checkboxe's ?

Comment: what is `$scope.checkboxOptions` ?

Comment: ng-model="$parent.checkboxAnswer"

Comment: ops sorry.. my question was "what is : `$scope.checkboxAnswer`" ? an array? an object?

Comment: actually i don't know exact..  because its showing  `undefined` in console. So i am not able say what it will show exact.

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yupii...i found the solution..

**here is solution:**

```
<ul>
        <label ng-repeat="opt in $parent.checkboxOptions">
            <li>
                <h4>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.$parent.selected[opt.option_value]" >{{opt.option_value}}</label>
                </h4>
            </li>
        </label>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ng-includes create it's own scope.
By using the `controller as` syntax you can overcome this issue.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

```
<div id="ctrl-as-exmpl" ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
   ...
    <li ng-repeat="opt in ctrl.checkboxOptions">
        <h4>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.checkboxAnswer" value="{{opt.option_value}}">{{opt.option_value}}</label>
        </h4>
    </li>
   ...
</div>
```

and in your controller :

```
$scope.checkboxOptions = params.QuestAnswers;
```

becomes

```
this.checkboxOptions = params.QuestAnswers;
```

and so on.

AngularJS plunker about this syntax :
https://plnkr.co/edit/DB1CpoWLUxQ9U8y558m1?p=preview

Regards,
Eric

Comment: yes, its showing list of all check boxes fine..but `$scope` or `this` still not able to access the `checkboxAnswer` values...

Comment: Can you make a plunker or a JSfillde reproducing your issue?

Comment: all my another code working perfectly..but problem is that i am  not able to access checkboxes value in my controller using `$scope` or `this`

Answer (score 0):

You need some correction in the html.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" ng-model="opt.option_value">{{opt.option_value}}</label>
```

With `ng-model="$parent.checkboxAnswer"` ,`all checkbox will share common model`.

So,it will get updated at the same time.

So,when you `check/uncheck`,it will `check/uncheck` everyone.

And ,you don;t need to use `value`,angular is used `ng-model` property for its value evaluation and not `value`

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl', SettingsController1);

  function SettingsController1($scope) {

    $scope.options = {
      'checkboxAnswer': ''
    };
    $scope.checkboxOptions= [{
      type: 'phone',
      value: '917xxxxxxxx'
    }, {
      type: 'email',
      value: 'sajankumarv@example.org'
    }];
  }


})(window.angular);
```

radio box template file #radiobox.html

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="opt in checkboxOptions">
    <h4>
            <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="options.checkboxAnswer" ng-true-value="'{{opt.value}}'" ng-false-value="''">{{opt.type}}</label>
        </h4>
  </li>

  <h1>{{options.checkboxAnswer}}</h1>

</ul>
```

//in main index.html you simply include this radiobox.html using ng-include directive

```
 <body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <div ng-include='"radiobox.html"'></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

I think you are not in isolate scope so you don't have to use $parent for your case.I made a simple working demo for you to understand kindly refer the below link. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/aQMZBln5t0Fipwn1qloN?p=preview

Comment: that is really simple. All you have to do is change the input type to checkbox and  add  ng-true-value="'{{opt.value}}'" ng-false-value="''" i have updated the code in demo please check.